# Regex to get HTML buttons and anchor tags without attribute

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to write a regex that will list me all `button`'s and `anchor` tags in a HTML document that do not have an `analytics-on` attribute.

I have two test situations:

```
<button class="btn"
    ng-click="doSomething()">Do something without analytics</button>
```

And

```
<button class="btn"
    ng-click="doSomething()"
    analytics-on analytics-event="Did something" analytics-category="Category">Do something with analytics</button>
```

The first should match but the second should not as it has the analytics tag.

So far I have:

```
/<(button|a)([^>]*)>/s
```

Which matches a `button` or `anchor` tag over multiple lines but does not look for the absence of `analytics-on` how can I check for this?

Comment: @zzzzBov Care to suggest one? I'm open to other options

Comment: Any DOM library ever.

Comment: @zzzzBov I was hoping to write a simple script so I could grep for these, I'm sure it's possible

Comment: No, regular expressions are the wrong approach; HTML is not a regular language. Use a parser. Python has BeautifulSoup, for example; `soup.select('button, a[href]')` would give you all buttons and `a` tags with a `href` attribute, for example.

Comment: Related, imfamous post on this subject: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348)

Comment: How is this related to Google Analytics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already suggested in the comments, you should definitely use an HTML parser.

However, if you just want to get a sense of how many buttons/anchors don't have this attribute for the sake of a technical analysis, grooming, etc. you can use this regex one-time only and then go use a HTML parser:

```
<(button|a)(?!([^>]*?)analytics-on)(?:[^>]*?)>(?:[^<]*)<\/(button|a)>
```

Working sample [here](https://regex101.com/r/vK9eH0/1).

Comment: Thanks. exactly what I needed. Needed to find tags in a react project and I don't think an html parser would have cut it.